# Python Selenium: Finds element but returns empty string

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get all players from this Page:
https://earthmc.net/map

(You can see them when you click on the arrow on the right side).

The tags for the players looks like this:`<a href="#" title="Center on player">Blu_Viper</a>`
I am using this code for this:

```py
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://earthmc.net/map/")

name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@title="Center on player"]')
for i in range(len(name)):
    print(name[i].text)

driver.close()
```

The driver finds the Xpath but it prints only a blank string.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Try .get_attribute('textContent')  instead of .text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:- Moreover, you can change the sleep timing as per your need. for your information, this code gives error sometimes because the list is pretty dynamic. But you can run it again to get the full player list.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
action = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get('https://earthmc.net/map/')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
time.sleep(20)

ExpandArrow = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="hitbar"]')))
action.move_to_element(ExpandArrow).perform()

PlayerList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[contains(@class,"player")]')

for element in PlayerList:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
    print(element.text)

print("Successfully Completed.")
```

Note - If this is what you are looking for then mark this as the answer.